# Can Debian 5 (Lenny) use SSL?

Tags: networking, ssl, internet

I have an old Debian 5 (Lenny) machine, and by default it has the Iceweasel internet browser. Whenever I attempt to access an HTTPS site, the browser throws an SSL error saying that it cannot be established. SSL/TLS v.1.2 has been around since 2008, and the final release of Debian 5 came out around 2009. I know that my hardware is able to make HTTPS connections when using a more recent version of Debian, but with this old Debian 5 machine, there are no available modern web browsers I can install to replace Iceweasel. Is this a browser issue, or an OS issue?

Comment: AFAIK, protocols older than TLS 1.2 had  been deprecated; if the browser tries to establish a connection with a older protocol and cannot renegotiate, the connection will fail, even if there is support for TLS 1.2 in the browser.

Comment: Also the certificate store is obsolete, the only way I can connect to https/ssl websites with my lenny install is to force a no check certificates. You may be able to get around this issue by manually installing either firefox or chrome from upstream sources, chrome only supports 64 bit however as of a year or two ago. But you can easily run firefox from the direct moxilla tar.gz package, it's easy to install, just put it in /opt/firefox then update your paths. No apt installed browser is going to work as far as I know, but you don't need it to be installed by apt, I use mozilla direct install

Comment: What version of iceweasel are you running? You might be able to change the supported TLS versions in `about:config`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your operating system generally supports TLS up to version 1.0, but this is 2017 and a large part of the Internet now requires TLS 1.2. Although the TLS 1.2 specification came out in 2008, it wasn't widely [adopted until much later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers). For example [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480514) only supports TLS 1.2 since version 24 which came out in 2013. [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90392) supports TLS1.2 since version 29 which came out the same year. The OpenSSL library, which most “lesser” browsers use, has only supported TLS 1.2 since version 1.0.1 in 2012.

Even with sites that still support TLS 1.0, you may have to click through invalid certificate warnings because the set of root certificate authorities has changed over time. And keep in mind that the reason older protocol versions are deprecated is that they have security flaws.

If you want to access HTTPS websites from your machine, you can use a man-in-the-middle proxy on a more modern system. Beware that a man-in-the-middle proxy works against the security properties offered by HTTPS, so it's difficult to use one securely. Don't transmit any confidential information this way. See [Is it possible to utilize an outbound proxy to upgrade to TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119813/is-it-possible-to-utilize-an-outbound-proxy-to-upgrade-to-tls) or [Proxy server accepting TLS 1.0 and calling TLS 1.2 downstream](https://serverfault.com/questions/822453/proxy-server-accepting-tls-1-0-and-calling-tls-1-2-downstream) for some software suggestions.